# iphone app how to do wheel animation

Tags: ios, animation, uipickerviewcontroller

I am working on app where it needs wheel animation like iPhone sony pictures app , is it possible with UIPickerview controller , or does any one has any sol?
Thank u in advance

[image]

Comment: Let's assume I don't have, or don't want to download, the iPhone Sony pictures app. Please include a description or screenshots of what you are looking for.

Comment: I've added a picture of what (I assume) he means.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the sort of thing I wrote [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) to do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and for adding the image.. I will use iCarousel  and let u know if I have any doubts.. Thank u..